# URL to download latest version of Apache (httpd)?

Tags: php, apache, sh

I'm writing a little bash script wherein I want to download the latest stable versions of Apache (httpd) and PHP.

**Clarification**: I'm not asking for the "current" version as of May 17th, 2012, I'm asking for the "latest" version as of whatever date the script is run (in the future).

What's the best way to do this?

I know I can get, for example, Apache from `http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi`, but I don't want to have to parse that page to find out what the latest version is and then submit the form to choose a mirror. Ideally I want to just be able to call on a single URL like:

```
wget http://httpd.apache.org/download/latest
```

But I evidently URLs like the above don't exist - or do they?

If not, what's the best way to make the script download the latest version?

Comment: Questions on SO generally relate to programming. While I am not sure this question would fit in, I definitely know that this is off-topic for SO. Please read the [faq]

Comment: I'm asking how to pragmatically identify and download the latest version of Apache - per the FAQ, "Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to generally relate to programming or software development in some way"... if this belongs somewhere else though, just let me know where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully, this will get you the latest build.

```
curl -s "http://archive.apache.org/dist/httpd/?C=M;O=D" | grep \>httpd\-*\.*\.*\.tar\.gz\< | head -n1 | cut -d\> -f 3 | cut -d\< -f 1
```

As of now it'll fetch `httpd-2.4.2.tar.gz`.

Next you can append it with `http://archive.apache.org/dist/httpd/{latest_build}` to download it.